# Filtering in views

Tags: views

I have a view with a list of nodes of a certain type. I would like to add a filter in the HTML in order to reduce the amount of items in the list.
Every item has a Term Reference field, I would like to add a checkbox for each term in order to do this.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well your question, in your filter criteria of your View configuration, you can select the option `Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it`.

Comment: Seems like a good solution +1. Tell you something if fits!